# Is there a standard for protecting application files from user interference outside of application

Tags: file, security

Sorry if I didn't express myself precisely in the title, I'll try to explain what i meant to say here.

My application uses a lot of small files like DB files, xml files, fonts, etc. There is folder and file presence check when application starts, but I would like to make sure that user can not accidentally change or delete some important file from disk.

Only thing that comes to mind is archiving files in few archives by usage frequency, changing archive extension to something unfamiliar and hiding those archives. 
But compressing and uncompressing those files all the time through application doesn't seem like efficient solution.

Is there some standard procedure for keeping those important files from tampering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Only thing that comes to mind is archiving files in few archives by usage frequency, changing archive extension to something unfamiliar and hiding those archives

That is security through obscurity, which is not a recommended practice.

Instead, use the file security mechanisms built-in to your operating system.  Allow appropriate file access only to a specific group/role or user, and ensure your application runs in that group/role or as that user.

Comment: All users must have full access to all files from application, there is no other way in this case, so except hiding or adding read only option to files (Windows OS) I see no other solution (I am a novice in programming).

Comment: I don't understand... you want users to have full access to the files, and you don't want them to have access to the files.  Can you state more clearly exactly how users should be able to access the files, both using the program and outside of the program?

Comment: Every user / PC has full access to all files through the application (network virtual drive). That also means that I can not control visibility setting in every PC connected to the network. Application can not restrict user to access those files. What I would like is to restrict some user to accidentally delete or change some application file manually through e.g. windows explorer (outside of application). At least to minimize that risk somehow.

Comment: Even if it is a virtual network drive, you can still control file permissions.  That is the accepted best practice for preventing users from doing things to files that they should not.  I cannot recommend anything else.

Comment: I'll have to find/learn more about that topic. I didn't know that I could selectively control file permissions. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Exactly as noted @Eric J., the essential thing is to use your OS file permissions (_right click_ /Properties/Security in Windows). Depending on your particular application, you could need more, e.g. to encrypt the contents of the files, to verify if the contents were not changed by using some hash like CRC, MD5, etc. But if it is just about an access to the files, setting file permissions will be probably pretty much enough.